# configuring serverName on Fedora

Tags: httpd, fedora

i installed lamp (mariadb, httpd, and php 7) on a local fedora 23 fresh install.

i imported all my website in the /var/www folder. now i juste want to configure properly all of those.

for exemple : 
in /etc/conf.d/mywebsite.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mywebsite.local

     DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite/public


   <Directory var/www/mywebsite/public>
       AllowOverride All
     Require all granted   
       Order allow,deny       
       Allow from all        
   </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

/in /etc/conf.d/drupal.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName  drupal.local 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal

    <Directory /var/www/drupal>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

1. AllowOverride All doesn't work : 
   in var/www/mywebsite/public/.htaccess

   `Options +FollowSymLinks 
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.com`

simply not working

2. the VirtualHost configuration is not only apply on serverName defined, but on all serverName : 
   localhost, drupal.local, mywebsite.local show the same thing : var/www/mywebsite/public's content. if i remove the mywebsite.conf , it's the /var/www/drupal's content.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the Directory directive outside the virtual host section.

```
<Directory var/www/mywebsite/public>
       AllowOverride All
     Require all granted   
       Order allow,deny       
       Allow from all        
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mywebsite.local
      DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite/public
 </VirtualHost>


<Directory /var/www/drupal>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName  drupal.local 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal
 </VirtualHost>
```